# mocking axios in jest is not mocking

Tags: jestjs, axios

I'm trying to mock axios which has the following code (extracted)

```js
const result = await axios.patch(url, { customerId: '12345' });
```

To that end in my unit test, I'm doing the following

```js
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
mockedAxios.patch.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 202 }));
```

However, when I run the code it does not run my mock, it just runs the plain axios library.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1. Use `jest.fn()` to create a mock function and replace the `axios.patch()` method.

Option 2. Use `jest.spyOn(axios, 'patch').mockResolvedValueOnce({})`

Option 3. `jest.mock('axios')` should work too, jest will mock a module with an auto-mocked version when it is required.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

async function getCustomer() {
  const url = 'https://github.com/mrdulin';
  const result = await axios.patch(url, { customerId: '12345' });
  return result;
}

export { getCustomer };
```

For example use option 1.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { getCustomer } from './';

describe('getCustomer', () => {
  it('t1', async () => {
    const url = 'https://github.com/mrdulin';
    axios.patch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ status: 202 });
    const actualValue = await getCustomer();
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({ status: 202 });
    expect(axios.patch).toBeCalledWith(url, { customerId: '12345' });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```bash
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57087200/index.spec.ts
  getCustomer
    ✓ t1 (8ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.608s
```